# Select format is broken

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell script which pulls account, Time and path from Bitvise logs

```bsh
gc C:\temp\all.log |
    Select-String -Pattern '<parameters path=\"([^\"]*)\"','virtualAccount=\"([^\"]*)\"' ,'time=\"([^\"]*)\"' |
    select @{n='path';e={$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}},
        @{n='Account';e={$_.Matches.Groups[2].Value}},
        @{n='time';e={$_.Matches.Groups[3].Value}}
```

logs look like

```xml
<event seq="993107" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="I_SFS_LIST_DIRECTORY" desc="Virtual filesystem: list directory.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="128.2.27.11:49312" virtualAccount=CMU" windowsAccount="SERVER\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="91000" desc="Listing directory ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\lyyyy\ff" timeMs="156" entriesCount="23"/>
   </sfs>
 </event>

 <event seq="993108" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="xxxx" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="0.090.0" virtualAccount="yyyyyy" windowsAccount="server\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\path\ttx" timeMs="109" bytesRead="0" bytesWritten="1772" readRangeOffset="0" readRangeLength="0" writeRangeOffset="0" writeRangeLength="1772" createdNewFile="false" resizedFile="true" endedBy="Client"/>
     <help message="File transfer ended by client."/>
   </sfs>
```

Its working fine but when I run to select the format its broken.

[image]

Comment: This looks like XML, but you missed the closing `</event>` and also the opening double-quote `"` on the `virtualAccount=CMU"`. Are these typos?

Comment: No they are bitvise logs in .log format, Not Typo I sanitize

Comment: Then you sanitized too much, because [here](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-guide-logparser) it says `Bitvise SSH Server's textual log files are recorded in a machine processable XML format.` Your XML is not valid at the moment. Also, Does it not have a root element?

Comment: Not at all, I just change the names.

Comment: Please have a GOOD look at my first comment and change `virtualAccount=CMU"` into `virtualAccount="CMU"`. (note the quote before `CMU`). Then add the missing `</event>` tag at the bottom and wrap it in the root element of the log file.

Comment: **[DO NOT PARSE XML WITH REGEX](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171).** With that said, `Select-String` processes the input *line by line*, meaning that not the format is broken, but your expection about how `Select-String` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having in mind that parsing a `XML` using regular expressions definitely is not a good idea (**updated** for Powershell 2 and above):

```
$logFile = @'
<event seq="993107" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="I_SFS_LIST_DIRECTORY" desc="Virtual filesystem: list directory.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="128.2.27.11:49312" virtualAccount="CMU" windowsAccount="SERVER\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="91000" desc="Listing directory ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\lyyyy\ff" timeMs="156" entriesCount="23"/>
   </sfs>
</event>

<event seq="993108" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="xxxx" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="0.090.0" virtualAccount="yyyyyy" windowsAccount="server\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\path\ttx" timeMs="109" bytesRead="0" bytesWritten="1772" readRangeOffset="0" readRangeLength="0" writeRangeOffset="0" writeRangeLength="1772" createdNewFile="false" resizedFile="true" endedBy="Client"/>
     <help message="File transfer ended by client."/>
   </sfs>
</event>
'@
# $log = $logFile -split [System.Environment]::NewLine       ### instead of Get-Content 
$log = $logFile.Split( [System.Environment]::NewLine )
$logExp = $log | Select-String -Pattern 'parameters path=\"([^\"]*)\"', 
                                        'virtualAccount=\"([^\"]*)\"' ,
                                        'time=\"([^\"]*)\"' -AllMatches
$logNew = $(0..($logExp.Count / 3 -1)) | 
    Select-Object @{n='path';e={$logExp[3 * $_+2].Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}},
        @{n='Account'; e={$logExp[3*$_+1].Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}},
        @{n='time';e={$logExp[3*$_+0].Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}}
$logNew
```

**Result**:

```
PS D:\PShell> D:\PShell\SO\54476444.ps1

path        Account time                            
----        ------- ----                            
C:\lyyyy\ff CMU     2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500
C:\path\ttx yyyyyy  2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500
```

**Powershell 2**:

```
==> powershell -version 2 -noprofile -file D:\PShell\SO\54476444.ps1

path                          Account                      time
----                          -------                      ----
C:\lyyyy\ff                   CMU                          2019-01-30 11:00:01.90306...
C:\path\ttx                   yyyyyy                       2019-01-30 11:00:01.96098...
```

Comment: It do not works, let me check with Powershell 3 and above, thanks anyway, logs are in .log format

Comment: @Jondrew answer **updated** for Powershell 2 (and above)

Comment: When I try from Powershell 
`path                                        Account                          time                                                                    
C:\lyyyy\ff                                 CMU                             2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500                                        
C:\path\ttx                               yyyyyy                            2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500   `

Comment: It is proper format, but when I use get-content its breaks date comes under path and account come under time

Comment: @Jondrew I don't understand. The script _works_ even if instead `$log = $logFile.Split( [System.Environment]::NewLine)` I run `$logFile | Out-File -FilePath 'C:\temp\all.log' -Encoding default;
$log = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\all.log'`. Hence, there must be something messed up in your file. For instance, unadjusted `virtualAccount=CMU"` in you originally posted example (instead of `virtualAccount="CMU"`) leads to described behaviour. Forget applying regex to `XML` data. Parse the log properly; see the latter approach in [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54479655/3439404).

Comment: Hye its fine, I just one of my colleague to test I guess its my version

Answer (score 2):

Once you have fixed your XML as commented, you can get the attribute values quite easily doing something like this:

```
# you would use Get-Content for this
$log = [xml]@"
<root>
 <event seq="993107" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="I_SFS_LIST_DIRECTORY" desc="Virtual filesystem: list directory.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="128.2.27.11:49312" virtualAccount="CMU" windowsAccount="SERVER\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="91000" desc="Listing directory ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\lyyyy\ff" timeMs="156" entriesCount="23"/>
   </sfs>
 </event>

 <event seq="993108" time="2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500" app="BvSshServer 7.45" name="xxxx" desc="Virtual filesystem: transfer file.">
   <session id="96172" service="SSH" remoteAddress="0.090.0" virtualAccount="yyyyyy" windowsAccount="server\BvSsh_VirtualUsers"/>
   <channel type="session" id="1"/>
   <sfs moduleName="FlowSfsWin" mountPath="/" code="90000" desc="Transferring file ended.">
     <parameters path="C:\path\ttx" timeMs="109" bytesRead="0" bytesWritten="1772" readRangeOffset="0" readRangeLength="0" writeRangeOffset="0" writeRangeLength="1772" createdNewFile="false" resizedFile="true" endedBy="Client"/>
     <help message="File transfer ended by client."/>
   </sfs>
 </event>
</root>
"@

foreach ($node in $log.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'Path' = $node.sfs.parameters.path
        'Account' = $node.session.virtualAccount
        'Time' = $node.time
    }
}
```

or this

```
foreach ($node in $log.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    "" | Select-Object @{name = 'Path'; expression = {$node.sfs.parameters.path}},
                       @{name = 'Account'; expression = {$node.session.virtualAccount}},
                       @{name = 'Time'; expression = {$node.time}}
}
```

or this

```
foreach ($node in $log.DocumentElement.ChildNodes) {
    $node | Select-Object @{name = 'Path'; expression = {$_.sfs.parameters.path}},
                          @{name = 'Account'; expression = {$_.session.virtualAccount}},
                          @{name = 'Time'; expression = {$_.time}}
}
```

The result will be:

> ```
> Path        Account Time                            
> ----        ------- ----                            
> C:\lyyyy\ff CMU     2019-01-30 11:00:01.903062 -0500
> C:\path\ttx yyyyyy  2019-01-30 11:00:01.960986 -0500
> ```

Comment: It do not works, let me check with Powershell 3 and above, thanks anyway, logs are in .log format

Comment: @Jondrew Ah, you did not tag this Powershell 2. `[PSCustomObject]` needs version 3 or higher.

Comment: NO issues the server has PS 5 I am on weekoff I will check that